# Javascript variable to Python

Tags: javascript, python, django-forms, leaflet

I'm working locally using Django, and I created a template of a map using Leaflet. After doing some research I find that you can let the user click on the map to create a Marker and then pressing a button (export) to download the geoJSON of every figure or marker the user created.

What I want to do is not to download the geoJSON but to store it on a Database (it could be locally). Im not proficient at JavaScript so I'm really really stuck.

This is the map code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/python-visualization/folium/master/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css"/>
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8 {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
            </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>

            <style>
                #export {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 5px;
                    right: 10px;
                    z-index: 999;
                    background: white;
                    color: black;
                    padding: 6px;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    top: 90px;
                }
            </style>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.2/leaflet.draw.css"/>
</head>
<body>

            <div class="folium-map" id="map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8" ></div>

    <a href='#' id='export'>Continue</a>
</body>
<script>

            var map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8 = L.map(
                "map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8",
                {
                    center: [46.8527, -121.7649],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 13,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );





            var tile_layer_0cce79173c4743718c558aeea7872020 = L.tileLayer(
                "https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg",
                {"attribution": "Map tiles by \u003ca href=\"http://stamen.com\"\u003eStamen Design\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0\"\u003eCC BY 3.0\u003c/a\u003e. Data by \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e, under \u003ca href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0\"\u003eCC BY SA\u003c/a\u003e.", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            ).addTo(map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8);


            var options = {
              position: "topleft",
              draw: {"polyline": {"allowIntersection": false}},
              edit: {"poly": {"allowIntersection": false}},
            }
            // FeatureGroup is to store editable layers.
            var drawnItems = new L.featureGroup().addTo(
                map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8
            );
            options.edit.featureGroup = drawnItems;
            var draw_control_ca0cd7071ba049ccb3dafbbf098f2b38 = new L.Control.Draw(
                options
            ).addTo( map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8 );
            map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e) {
                var layer = e.layer,
                    type = e.layerType;
                var coords = JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON());
                layer.on('click', function() {
                    alert(coords);
                    console.log(coords);
                });
                drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
             });
            map_a3375e0d166f4ec89fd79df498d1f8b8.on('draw:created', function(e) {
                drawnItems.addLayer(e.layer);
            });

            document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
                var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
                var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,'
                    + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
                document.getElementById('export').setAttribute(
                    'href', 'data:' + convertedData
                );
                document.getElementById('export').setAttribute(
                    'download', "my_data.geojson"
                );
            }


</script>
```

And I know this is the part I have to change

```
            document.getElementById('export').onclick = function(e) {
                var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
                var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,'
                    + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
                document.getElementById('export').setAttribute(
                    'href', 'data:' + convertedData
                );
                document.getElementById('export').setAttribute(
                    'download', "my_data.geojson"
                );
            }
```

Could anyone give me some direction/tutorial of how to acchieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  It's as close to a simple web request as you can get!

Your code might look like this:

```
        // async function here allows you to use "await" keyword.
        document.getElementById('export').onclick = async function(e) {

            var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();

            // make the request:
            var rsp = await fetch("path/to/server/upload/url", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            });

            console.log("server responded with: ", await rsp.json());
        }
```

EDIT:
The answer to your question HIGHLY depends on which database technology you are using. Some database servers host an HTTP API that allows you to `fetch` directly to them, such as [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/), but this is exceedingly uncommon, even when using Couch (for security reasons, JavaScript in your browser has VERY limited IO options).

Here's the (by far) most common way to approach this problem:

1. send geoJSON from browser to server (code example above)
2. server saves JSON to database

You have stated you are using Django. That's the server tech in #2.

On the server, the path you will take is:

1. create a [Django Route](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/) at the URL endpoint where you put your `path/to/server/upload/url`
2. In the route's python function, you will save the data to the database connected to Django.

In Django, database interactions are typically done via [Django's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/), but you can use any methodology you want at this point.

The code above shows you how to get the geoJSON data from browser JS to your Django server so you can save it to a DB.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have a question, in this part should I paste the path to my local database? await fetch("path/to/server/upload/url"

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - the OP is looking for a solution  to store the data in a database, not upload the file to a server.